# Is there a way to customize SQL Server Performance Dashboard?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

The report in SQL Server Management Studio presents System CPU Utilization broken out by a minute.  Is there a way to specify the interval - perhaps by 10 seconds?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not. This information comes from the sys.dm_os_ring_buffers DMV, where it uses the RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR record type. This information is produced every minute, and that is not customizable. I.e., it isn't the reports "fault", it is the information that is lacking in the first place.

Below is the query that this report is using, captured by a trace:

```
exec sp_executesql @stmt=N'
          declare @ms_now bigint
          select @ms_now = ms_ticks from sys.dm_os_sys_info;
          select top 15 record_id,
          dateadd(ms, -1 * (@ms_now - [timestamp]), GetDate()) as EventTime,
          SQLProcessUtilization,
          SystemIdle,
          100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization as OtherProcessUtilization
          from (
          select
          record.value(''(./Record/@id)[1]'', ''int'') as record_id,
          record.value(''(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]'', ''int'') as SystemIdle,
          record.value(''(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]'', ''int'') as SQLProcessUtilization,
          timestamp
          from (
          select timestamp, convert(xml, record) as record
          from sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
          where ring_buffer_type = N''RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR''
          and record like ''%SystemHealth%'') as x
        ) as y 
    order by record_id desc',@params=N''
```